# Sending JWT RefreshToken as Set-Cookie

Tags: api, cookies, jwt, apollo-client, apollo-server

A short question about what is right or wrong when setting JWT refresh token as a cookie.

Should my API send the `refresh token` within it's response headers to the ApolloServer so `Set-Cookie` header will be passing down through my Apollo-server automatically to te client (apollo-client). Or should I expect just a body dataset from my API including token + refreshToke which I will extract via `apollo-server` middleware to append as a cookie to the client response myself.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies must be set by the server. This would be done using the express response object as such. Make sure it's accessible from your gql context.

```
res.cookie('X-Refresh-Token', refreshToken, {
  maxAge: 900000,    // 15 minutes in milliseconds
  httpOnly: true,    // ensure the cookie will not be exposed
  secure: true,      // set this in production to ensure HTTPS
  sameOrigin: 'none' // set this in production if the server is separate domain
})
```

Then, your client must have credentials enabled. For apollo-boost, this would be:

```
new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
  credentials: 'include', // 'same-origin' if your server is same domain
})
```

To ensure cookies are passed in GraphQL Playground:

```
new ApolloServer({
  context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'request.credentials': 'include',
    },
  },
})
```

And if you're not already using it, the [cookie parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) may come in handy.

Comment: So, the `x-refresh-token` needs to be send by the API with the Set-Cookie header to the apollo-server which will push it down to the client?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The apollo-server is essentially just express middleware. By using the express response object, you should be able to set the cookie like this.